# GoJS canvas (canvas2d) blurry on 100% zoom

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, gojs

I'm trying to use GoJS to create some nodes using rounded rectangles and some text. This results in the following blurry rendering (at 100% zoom):

[image: blurry node]

Not changing anything except opening the dev console (this acts like decreasing zoom it seems) results in the sharp image:

[image: sharp node]

A similar look is achievable when zooming out to 80%. Is there any setting, ... I can adjust to get the crisp look at 100% zoom?

The same is true for the attribution text in the upper left corner:

[image: Attribution]  [image: Sharp attribution]

Comment: what is your node template here? Does this happen for you on the samples eg https://codepen.io/simonsarris/pen/ORwoLr?editors=1010

Comment: Yes, it also happens with this sample. But: I just noticed that it relates to my Windows UI scaling (that is set to 125% on one PC, here it is blurry and gets sharp at 80% zoom; on another with the scaling at 100% it is already sharp at 100% zoom). Since 80% zoom with a UI scaling of 125% is exactly the 100% again.

So it seems my question is rather: How to adjust to the Win UI scaling factor?

Comment: Are you talking about `diagram.scale` for the zoom? Or Chrome's browser zoom? Or some other zoom?

Comment: I am talking about just zooming out using the Browser. It seems like the whole `<canvas>` gets upscaled to 125% (from the "outside" due to the Win UI scaling) which makes it blurry. Setting my browser zoom to 80% cancels that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might have to do with the pixel ratio, but it's not quite clear to me why.

You can query the pixel ratio GoJS uses by calling `myDiagram.computePixelRatio()` in the console. This typically changes dynamically during drag operations.

You can customize the pixel ratio GoJS uses by setting it to a new function:

```js
myDiagram.computePixelRatio = function() { return 3; }
```

Comment: The pixel ratio is `2` on both PCs that I tested on (one where it's working, one where it's not). I've tried your approach (with `3`) and that seems to fix it. Which I don't quite understand, since that does not correlate with the UI scale of 125%. So I've now set it to `2.5` which looks exactly the same. I'll consider this "solved", thanks a lot!